# Is it possible to offer bounty on the same question twice?

Tags: support, bounty

Recently I've offered bounty for a question. It already ended and in 10 hrs gonna be auto-awarded(2 answers with more than 2 votes).  Now I want to increase the bounty amount, I guess its not possible.

Suppose I award to one question now. Can I able to open another bounty on it (AFAIK, minimum is twice of the previous bounty ) and allow it to the desired question later on ? If yes how soon ?

Comment: According to [Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68050/a-grace-period-of-one-day-to-award-the-bounty-after-expiration-without-remainin/74037#74037) the bounty ends after 7 days. The grace period is separate from that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As soon as your previous bounty is awarded or completely expired (meaning even the grace period ended), you can start another one.

The minimal amount of new bounty is twice the previous bounty or 500, whichever is smaller.